# cordova update android version without any loss

Tags: android, cordova, updates, data-loss

I was trying to update my android version in my cordova project using this command:

```
cordova platform update android
```

But this was the response:

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
Updating android project...
(node:4188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: An in-place platform update is not supported. 
The `platforms` folder is always treated as a build artifact in the CLI workflow.
To update your platform, you have to remove, then add your android platform again.
Make sure you save your plugins beforehand using `cordova plugin save`, and save 
a copy of the platform first if you had manual changes in it.
    cordova plugin save
    cordova platform rm android
    cordova platform add android

(node:4188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4188) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I worried if I do so, I will lose some customisations I did (like losing the app icons, splash screens and i edited a method so the keyboard is visible when the app is in full-screen mode )

Can it be done some how?

Comment: Can you tell me more on where you have put your app icons and splash screens?

Comment: Like in the docs https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/config_ref/images.html

Answer (score 0):

The app icons, splash screens and other resources are outside the `platforms` folder. Removing and readding the android platform will only erase contents from the `platforms/android` folder.

You should only worry if you have **manually edited something from certain platform inside the platforms folder**, generally you don't need to. This practice is heavily discouraged, not by me but the Apache Cordova guides, and they are totally correct: always avoid manual edits from the platforms folder, unless you are absolutely certain that there's no other way.

Comment: you definitely lose your `platforms/android/build.gradle` file, thankfully i was able to restore it's content from the repository

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet that's what I said, but that build.gradle file is auto generated when adding the platform/building again.

Comment: In my case yes, but all the customisations I did, were lost, also the androidManifest which it was not generated. I'll have to ask another question because i can't build Android..

Answer (score 0):

**Changes in app icons and splash**

The app icons and splash are residing in the `resources` folder so if you delete your platform it won't affect anything. If you have manually added any icon make sure to put an entry in config.xml before your update.

**Changes in any plugin**

If you have changed any plugin then do the following steps

- Detect the plugin for which you have changed your code.
- Search for the plugin repo and fork it.
- Change whatever you did it in your platform's code.
- Push your code to GitHub.
- Remove that plugin(`cordova plugin rm <plugin_id>`).
- Add the plugin (`cordova plugin add https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx`).
  (If you think your method will be helpful for others' then you can also raise a PR in the parent plugin)