# Cordova fails to build Android

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build

This is after running (to [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471949/cordova-update-android-version-without-any-loss) android):

```
cordova plugin save
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

This is the error I get, which I think is that version values are not being merged properly.

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-35:19 to override.
```

I've been having this issue and digging into for a few days.

Lets see, I'll share only what I think is relevant but if any more info is needed. just let me know:

**config.xml**

```
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
        ...
</platform>

<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^3.0.1">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="28.+" />
</plugin>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>
```

And I even tried this in my **build.gradle** (which I found in a answer for a related question that it seems to solve it for the QO):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is if I change all this `28`'s for `27` then `cordova build android` will still say 28:

```
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/myuser/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/myuser/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/my-cordova-android-support-gradle
```

So I don't really know what to try next.. any thoughts?

This is the full response:

```
cordova build android
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/my-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Running command: /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/hooks/after_prepare/030_remove-permissions.js /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '28.+' to /Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/cordova-android-support-gradle-release/my-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/toniweb/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 28.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-35:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-35:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
22 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 21 up-to-date
/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/toniweb/Proyectos/localhost/cordova/my-app/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-35:19 to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-35:19 to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Have you tried putting android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true in your gradle.properties

Comment: @Swayangjit thanks! I tried and the response now is `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.`. Any other thought?

Comment: Can you post the please complete log ?

Comment: @Swayangjit I posted my previos full log in the question and this is the full log including your suggestion on `gradle.properties`, its significantly larger: https://hastebin.com/pumozasiti.shell hope it helps to find the problem. Thanks

Comment: Add <preference name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" default="27.+"/>
 <framework src="com.android.support:supportv4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION"/>    in your config.xml

Comment: The error doesn't seem to change: https://jsfiddle.net/trjs3yhu/

Comment: can you show me the config.xml where you have added above statement ?

Comment: This is it (replacing app names and authors): https://jsfiddle.net/om5nte62/ thanks for your time

Comment: Can you put one answer so that it might be helpful for others?

Comment: What? I'm passing you my config.xml as you requested. Problem persists

Comment: oh srry I think this solved your issue.

Comment: put <preference name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" default="27.+"/> <framework src="com.android.support:supportv4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION"/> inside platform android section

Comment: same result :( but why do i need this line? `android.useAndroidX=true`

Comment: That is to specify if you want to use android arch components or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your plugins is using an Android X dependency, which is not compatible with the regular android support dependencies.

You'll have to search which plugin is that and remove it or use a previous version that didn't use an Android X dependency.

Alternatively, use the Cordova Android X plugins that enable Android X in the project and patch plugin dependencies and code usage for the Android X equivalent.

Install `cordova-plugin-androidx` to enable Android X

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`

Then install `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` to patch existing plugins

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

And remove `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` and any gradle code where you try to force the support version to 28 as it will conflict with the Android X changes.

Comment: Thanks for your time, excuse my delay. Ok, I installed both plugins and commented this line `<!-- variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="28.+" /-->` response changed slightly but is the same error. I rm and added the platform again so those I believe other gradles configs are gone.. any thoughts?

Comment: what's the new error? did you uninstall cordova-android-support-gradle-release?

Comment: Hi, no I did not, just commented the line above. How could I do it? `cordova plugin remove cordova-android-support-gradle-release`? This is the "new" log: https://pastebin.com/edMrP1dG

Comment: I did try the command and it did remove the plugin, this is the log now after `cordova prepare` and `cordova build android`: https://pastebin.com/JitAm0sQ

Comment: Looks like some plugin is setting minsdk to 15 but cordova requires 19, so you’ll have to set the minsdk in the config.xml to 19

Comment: to set the minSDK add this to the config.xml `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />`

Answer (score 0):

There is any of you installed plugin which is not support with your android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactor therefor menifest.xml is unable to merge.
remove your plugin and try again and if you need this plugin then check its old version it will help you to run project

Comment: Thanks! the thing is that i don't know what plugins is... this is my plugin list. any thoughts? https://pastebin.com/VLEefWiW

Answer (score 0):

you just Add two lines in gradle.properties file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

hope this will resolve your issue